# Python/SQLite: Error inserting datetime.time variable into column of type Time

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

I am having trouble passing a `datetime.time` variable into a SQLite database, I have some very basic code here to show what exactly the variable is.

```
import datetime as dt

time = dt.datetime.now().time() 
time = time.strftime('%H:%M') 
time = dt.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M').time()

print(time)
print(type(time))
```

`time = dt.datetime.now().time()` gets the current time in type `datetime.time`.

*Output:*

```
17:34:48.286215
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

`time = time.strftime('%H:%M')` is then retrieving just the hour and minute but is of type `str`

*Output:*

```
17:35
<class 'str'>
```

I then convert it back to a datetime.time with `time = dt.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M').time()` which gives the the output:

```
17:32:00
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

The column of type `Time` accepts the format of HH:SS as shown in the documentation ([SQLite3 DateTime Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#:%7E:text=THH%3AMM%3ASS.SSS-,HH%3AMM,-HH%3AMM%3ASS)), so I am not sure why I am getting this error:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 11 - probably unsupported type.
```

From this INSERT statement:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO booked_tickets VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (booking_ref, ticket_date, film, showing, ticket_type, num_tickets, cus_name, cus_phone, cus_email, ticket_price, booking_date, booking_time, ))
```

EDIT: As requested, here is a snippet of code to recreate the table with the broken columns:

```
import datetime as dt
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("your_database.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Get the current time
time = dt.datetime.now().time()

# Format the time as a string using the '%H:%M' format
time_str = time.strftime('%H:%M')

# Parse the string back to a time object using the '%H:%M' format
time = dt.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M').time()

# Create the table
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test (example_time Time)")

# Insert the time into the example_time column
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)", (time, ))

connection.commit()

connection.close()
```

Comment: you will have a better chance of a menaingfull answer if you modify your question to have a minimal reproducible example of your code. As for the time variable examples you are good, but then you miss it for the sqlite statement example, where we can't see how the table was created, and there are 11 other columns _AND_ Python variables we don´t care about.

Please  edit your question to add a python-sqlite statement to build a table that will cause the error you are seeing, with as few columns as needed (1?) to reproduce the error.

Comment: Sqlite does not have datatypes.  All columns are strings.  So, just convert your datetime objects back to the string representation.

Comment: @jsbueno I have added a snippet to recreate the table

Comment: @TimRoberts Would it just be a case of inserting it into the table as a string and then converting it to `datetime.time` after retrieving it?

Comment: Right.  You need an export/import process that converts from your internal format to what SQLite has/expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Date or Time [data type in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

The documentation from the link that you have in your question clearly states that in SQLite you can store datetime in 3 ways: text in ISO-8601 format, integer unix epochs and float julian days.

If you chose the first way then you should pass strings:

```
booking_date = dt.datetime.now().date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
booking_time = dt.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:00') 
sql = "INSERT INTO booked_tickets VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cursor.execute(sql, (booking_ref, ticket_date, film, showing, ticket_type, num_tickets, cus_name, cus_phone, cus_email, ticket_price, booking_date, booking_time))
```

But, you could also let SQLite get the current date and/or time.

Assuming that in the columns `booking_date` and `booking_time` you want the current date and time, you can define these columns as:

```
booking_date TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, 
booking_time TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
```

and then you don't need to pass anything for them in the `INSERT` statement:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO booked_tickets VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cursor.execute(sql, (booking_ref, ticket_date, film, showing, ticket_type, num_tickets, cus_name, cus_phone, cus_email, ticket_price,))
```

Comment: Will `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_TIME` make it so that when a new row is added to the table, it will automatically add the current date and time?

Comment: @Callum yes, in UTC time. If you want local date/time: `booking_date NOT NULL DEFAULT (date('now', 'localtime')), booking_time NOT NULL DEFAULT (time('now', 'localtime'))`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you refer to mostly discusses how to format column values that representing dates and times.  That is, it discusses what you can do with dates and times that already exist in your database.

It does, however, give just enough information to help you here I think.  It says:

> Date and time values can be stored as
>
> - text in a subset of the ISO-8601 format,
> - numbers representing the Julian day, or
> - numbers representing the number of seconds since (or before) 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (the unix timestamp).

So you want to define and supply your dates and times as either full ISO-8601 date strings or as numbers. When defining a table, you indicate which of these formats you wish to use by defining a column type as a STRING, REAL or INTEGER respectively.

Here's some documentation that discusses how to store dates and times in one of these formats: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [SQLite datatypes documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> 2.2. Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
> and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
> are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
> values:
>
> ```
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic
> ```
>
> Gregorian calendar.
> INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can choose to store dates and times in any of these
> formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
> time functions.

Store the dates as TEXT datatypes.

Comment: Even with a `TEXT` datatype the error persists

Comment: Perhaps the booking_time value is not ISO-8601 specific. Is it possible you can combine the date and time columns and write the full date and time (ISO-8601) to one column instead? Or you can let SQLite specify the date and time separately as explained by  [forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75011666/2985691)